# Passing parameters to testNG provider

Tags: xml, testng, dataprovider

I'm new to this, the information is not covered in TestNG docs, and I would like to just understand a few things, if anyone can help me.

```
@DataProvider(name="test1")
public Object[][] provideTestParam(ITestContext context){
    String testParam = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter(test_param);
    return new Object[][]{{ testParam }};
}

@Test(dataProvider="test1")
public void testData(String data){

    //...
}
```

1. Does anyone know what is `test_param`? Is it a file name, a method some parameter in the testng.xml file?
2. I looked at a javadoc for `ITestContext` and I don't clearly understand how does `getParameter` work. Does it get a single hash map from the xml file that the data is coming from? Or does it get all key value pairs from the xml file that the data is coming from?
3. All I want to do is have an xml file stored in my project and use the data from the xml file. Feed it to the dataprovider and run my tests. Is there another way to do this?
4. Can `getParameter` get values from within the testng.xml `<test>` node OR `<class>` node?

Answer (score 1):

1. No idea, `test_param` doesn't appear in the code snippet.
2. The parameters exposed in `ITestContext` are the ones found in `testng.xml`.
3. Sure, you will want to parse your own XML file and then return what you found as an `Object[][]`.

All this is explained in details in the various sections of [the documentation](http://testng.org), feel free to ask again if you have more questions.

Comment: No, the word "ITestContext" is not found even once in the documentation, nor is the phrase "test context".

Comment: I found five mentions in http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html alone, and of course, there's the Javadoc and the examples.

Comment: I am honored by your help Cedric.  You are right and I am so glad I commented because now I discovered this: "Any \@Before and \@After methods can declare a parameter of type XmlTest, which contain the current <test> tag." . Incredible! Also, I just don't quite understand this sentence in the docs: "TestNG lets you declare additional parameters in your methods." The example they provide is very vague.  My best guess is they are saying my test method can look like this:   void testIt( XmlTest thisTest ) .  Does that sound right?

Comment: This comment is followed by a list of all the parameters that you can add to your test methods and that TestNG will inject for you.

Comment: In my humble opinion only, in the places where you say "can declare a parameter" I think it would have been less confusing if you said "can consume an optional parameter".